# Listener won't be notified when dispatch-ing a KeyEvent (or any kind of event?)

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener

**This is not a question for key events in specific. I use KeyEvents/KeyListeners and a JButton as an example. All I want is to be able to fire listeners in JUnit tests conviniently.**

I am trying to fire a key listener in unit tests, but for some reason the listener is not fired.

```
 public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicBoolean keyReleasedRan = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                keyReleasedRan.set(true);
            }
        });

        int modifiers = 100; //Something, we don't care
        int keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_A; //something realistic
        KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(button, KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, System.currentTimeMillis() + 200,
                modifiers, keyCode, 'a');

        button.dispatchEvent(event);

        System.out.println("KEY RELEASED RAN: " + keyReleasedRan.get());
    }
}
```

I have tried multiple arguments in the event constructor in case it plays a role, but still the listener is never fired.

The only approach that it works but I really do not want to follow, is to iterate through `KeyListener`(s) and call `keyReleased()` method for each listener.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

I tried another components instead of a JButton but same results.

Comment: 1) For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson No, no. This is not about key events in specific. This is about any kind of events. I want to fire listeners through JUnit tests. I know about key bindings. The KeyEvent/KeyListener was just an example. About the SSCCE, I added. I thought JUnit test cases are considered some sort of minimal examples too, but whatever.

Comment: If you put the button in a JFrame, activate the JFrame and call the event on the button its working

Comment: @Ofek *activate the frame* means `frame.setVisible(true)`?

Comment: Try *button.doClick(0);*

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc `doClick` will fire only the action listener of a button. And YES! for Action Listeners, I use doClick() in order to test them. What about other listeners? What about other components?

Comment: I've always tested by running the GUI.  Of course, I write a tiny bit of code and test it.  Then another tiny bit of code and test.  Tiny bits of code.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments said, if you attach it to a JFrame, it works.

As you're using it in a Unit Test, you also want to automatically close the JFrame.
So I've added `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);`
and `frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));`.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JButton button = new JButton("Run");
        button.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("runs...");
            }
        });
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(button);
        frame.setSize(50, 50);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    
    
        int modifiers = InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK; //Something, we don't care
        int keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_A; //something realistic
        KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(button, KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, System.currentTimeMillis() + 200,
            modifiers, keyCode, 'a');
    
        button.dispatchEvent(event);
        frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
    }
}
```

Comment: `frame.setVisible(true)` is not an option for unit tests. Actually, building a `JFrame` is not an option for tests. Simply because it is expensive.